# Exchange Certification missing from Exchange Powershell after import

Tags: powershell, ssl, certificate, exchange

I'm trying to renewal a certification through MMC, Powershell and Exchange Powershell. After importing through the MMC gui and Powershell I can find the thumbprint no problem. However I cannot find it in Exchange Powershell. I'm wondering if this is related also to my inability to validate the certification through the Exchange Server Admin.

Instead I get an error that the Thumbprint is already in use and the server continues to loop this issue whenever I give the path to the certification.

Thus far I've removed the cert and reinstalled it through the three methods above.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that importing could be invalid if you just import the certificate through MMC, PowerShell.

You could import the new certificate on the Exchange Server by following the steps of Microsoft official document introducing:

1. Use EAC to import a certificate on the Exchange Server.
   [image]
2. Use EMS to import.

   Cmdlet: ***Import-ExchangeCertificate -FileName "\" -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String ' ' -AsPlainText -Force) [-PrivateKeyExportable ] [-Server ]***

More details about How to Import certificates on the Exchange Server: **[Import certificates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/architecture/client-access/import-certificates?view=exchserver-2019)**

I found some threads about A certificate with the thumbprint already exists and you could refer to them:

•   https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e32e9baf-7769-430d-9b52-9f53044c0644/cannot-import-certificate-a-certificate-with-the-thumbprint-xxx-already-exists?forum=exchangesvradmin

•   https://supertekboy.com/2015/10/23/a-certificate-with-the-thumbprint-already-exists/

Answer (score 0):

It appears in this case that the cert was in fact revoked by godaddy. I still donot have a clear cut explanation as to why it was revoked or even how to check if a cert has been revoked till i submitted a ticket with godaddy. After I got a replacement cert I imported it through EAS and it validated successfully. Thank you all for your help.